# Upload File On ftp by Creating Directories in Path

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp

I want to upload a file on ftp and i am able to do so with help of apple sample Code https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243-Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt-DontLinkElementID_16
 but the problem is while uploading the file if the directories not available on ftp server it should create it automatically. 
For Example:

if my address is 
    `192.168.1.100/fileTest/firstDirectory/secondDirectory/myfile.txt`

My question is the code should check if `fileTest/firstDirectory/secondDirectory/` this path exist or not. If not instead of giving me the stream error it should create the directories and upload my file.

Is this Possible. Any Ideas.. ? Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Hi, Did you solve this? i want exact same thing.